# Wiring two applications in lotus notes

Tags: hyperlink, lotus-notes, composite

I need to wire two applications so that one reacts when another is selected.

I need a calendar view (populated in one application) to update when a person is selected from a list (based from another application).

I have been trying to do this for absolutely ages and have hit a brick wall as the existing knowledge base is pretty poor. I don't understand how to compose the action required to do this, or how to use the WDSL system to wire the two, which i will be linking using the UNID of the person.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using 8.x+. Look up this example in the designer help: [Example 1 - Simple composite application creation using Lotus Notes components](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SIMPLE_COMPAPP_EXAMPLE_OVERVIEW.html)